# How to remove _afxdll in compiler options?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm using _afxdll option in my c++ project.Because of this i have to use /MD switch also.Now i need to compile the same project using /MT switch but _afxdll is creating problem.I tried removinf _afxdll option but on compiling it throws many error.How to remove this option?

Comment: What error do you get when `_afxdll` is included?

Comment: When tried with /MT switch as i require this option following error comes:fatal error C1189: #error :  Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.